# sql database query from amazon s3 website

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

ok, basically what i would like to do is query a database to build a simple table on my website. i'm using amazon tools for everything. the database is built in simpledb and works fine. however, making queries from my index.html requires php, which will not run on s3. sooooo i need help coming up with a workaround. the database does not get updated very often, so what i'm thinking is that maybe i could use the output from it to generate a plain text file on the server that could be used to build the table in the index.html file. the html file would need to count rows in the db file but maybe i can automate an action that will insert the correct number of rows into the static file? haha i'm stuck please help.

Comment: Please include your best attempt that doesn't work to give context to your question.  And don't extend your question via comments.  Please delete your comment and update your question so the full story is all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. What I ended up doing was creating an EC2 instance for the sole purpose of hosting index.php, which queries the db and assembles the page from the resources stored on S3.

Comment: From what you described, it seems like you could have just built the table and saved the whole thing, already rendered, on S3.